# Не срабатывает onclick на шторке модального окна (без jQuery)

Tags: javascript

Внимание, тут только чистый JavaScript, все любители jQuery сразу идите мимо — помешаете.

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт, который добавляет кнопочку. По нажатию на неё появляется модальное окно. По нажатию на фон модального окна должно скрываться обратно (display: none). Очевидно, что я чего-то не вижу, прошу помощи.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Привет</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #cbWidgetButton {
            background: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 5px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #cbWrapModal {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: none;
        }

        #cbContainerModal {
            width: 40%;
            height: 50px;
            background: #fff;
            position: fixed;
            top: 20px;
            left: 30%;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    higimo
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(w, d) {
    /*
     * Конструктор виджета
     */
    var cbWidget = function(params) {
        if (params === undefined || params.user_id === undefined) {
            console.log('exit'); return false
        }
        this.body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
        this.modal = 0
        this.widget = 0

        this.initModal()
        this.initWidget()
    }

    cbWidget.prototype.initModal = function() {
        this.body.innerHTML +=
            '<div id="cbWrapModal"></div>' +
            '<div id="cbContainerModal">' +
                '<input type="text">' +
                '<button>Helo</button>' +
            '</div>'

        console.log(document.getElementById('cbContainerModal'))
        document.getElementById('cbWrapModal').onclick = function() {
            this.style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById('cbContainerModal').style.display = 'none'
        }
    }

    cbWidget.prototype.initWidget = function() {
        this.body.innerHTML += '<div id="cbWidgetButton">Hello</div>'
        document.getElementById('cbWidgetButton').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('cbWrapModal').style.display = 'block'
            document.getElementById('cbContainerModal').style.display = 'block'
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        w.cbWidget = new cbWidget({
            baseUrl: "http://gmcf.lo/",
            user_id: 1,
            site_id: 1
        })
    }
}(window, document)


</script>
<h1>Higimo</h1>
<div class="openOffice">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае выполняется onclick, повешенный последним, т.к. прямо перед тем, как его повесить, вы не просто дополняете body новым блоком cbWidgetButton, а переписываете все содержимое body с содержимым дополненным новым блоком.